# Strip, store and index HTML files in Solr

Tags: html, xml, solr

I'm trying to search a collection of HTML files and also provide excerpts in Solr 6.4.1. And since the highlighting needs to return clean readable text, the HTML needs to be stripped down to bare text and stored.

But no matter what I change in the core's configuration, the field I'm specifying does not get returned in the result and highlighting for the document is always empty {}.

**managed-schema:**

```
  <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_html" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <field name="content1" type="text_en_splitting_html" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml** is the default one, with the default /update/extract requestHandler. The response I'm getting is:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "hl":"on",
      "indent":"on",
      "hl.fl":"content1",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1488077854581"}},
  "response":{"numFound":100,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/home/me/files/d1/test.html",
        "stream_size":[62963],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"],
        "creator":["createhtml"],
        "stream_content_type":["text/html"],
        "viewport":["width=device-width, initial-scale=1"],
        "dc_title":["A nice read"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "resourcename":["/home/me/files/d1/test.html"],
        "title":["A nice read"],
        "creator_url":["http://createhtml.net"],
        "content_type":["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],
        "_version_":1560362957551960064}
...
},
  "highlighting":{
    "/home/me/files/d1/test.html":{},
...
```

I'm indexing with

```
/opt/solr/bin/post -c mycollection -filetypes html files/
```

I've also tried with the **Tika** extract handler

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="fmap.Last-Modified">last_modified</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

but with limited success. A "content" field now appears in the response and it contains what appears to be a poorly stripped and badly formatted version of the initial document. Highlighting appears to work but it's not clean.

So what I need Solr to do is:

- clean up my HTML entirely (no tags, class names, or inline styles - just like JavaScript's .text() method)
- perform the search on the stripped content
- return the stripped content if I ask it to
- return the highlighting on the stripped content

It seems that no matter what I change (except Tika above), "content1" is ignored.

All I'm trying to do here, simply put, is be able to search HTML files and provide excerpts like any other search engine.

Comment: Can you determine in the Solr server frontend whether there is actual content in the content1 field? If yes, can you use the `fl` parameter in your query with the content1 field and does that change the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to make this work and Tika would not correctly strip the HTML, so I fixed this by using the [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) PHP Client for Solr and PHPQuery to parse, strip, extract data, then form my own document to post directly to Solr.

The problem was the ERH (ExtractRequestHandler) defined in **solrconfig.xml** which was enforcing the use of Tika. By using Solarium, the ERH was bypassed so all fields I defined in **managed-schema** started being used by the /update request handler.